# Compress image at the time of uploading

Tags: ios, image, compression

I want to upload image on server. 
But before uploading i want to compress that image and then upload to server. I dont want to upload image more than 2 mb.
I have used this logic but if image size is to large then it runs no. of loops and also occupied memory increased to 1 gb during processing.

```
 double compressionRatio=1;
 NSData *imgData=UIImagePNGRepresentation(proImage.image,compressionRatio);
   while ([imgData length]>50000) {
    compressionRatio=compressionRatio*50;
    imgData=UIImageJPEGRepresentation(proImage.image,compressionRatio);
   }
```

Comment: Why are you using PNG representation before `while` loop? And `compressionRatio` should be between 0.0 (max compression) and 1.0 (no compression). Documentation is your friend: https://developer.apple.com/library/iOS/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIKitFunctionReference/Reference/reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40006894-CH3-SW9

Comment: @rokjarc  tell me then how to compress image before sending it to server

Comment: 2MB is Equal to 2097152 bytes not 50000 bytes.

Answer (score 0):

Please take a look at [UIImageJPEGRepresentation documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/iOS/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIKitFunctionReference/Reference/reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40006894-CH3-SW9).

```
NSData * UIImageJPEGRepresentation (
   UIImage *image,
   CGFloat compressionQuality
);

compressionQuality = 0.0; ... max compression
compressionQuality = 1.0; ... min compression
```

You could try something like:

```
NSData *imgData=UIImagePNGRepresentation(proImage.image,compressionRatio);

if ([NSData length] > maxSizeThatYouWant) {

    CGFloat compressionNeeded = (CGFloat)[NSData length]/(CGFloat)maxSizeThatYouWant;

    imgData=UIImageJPEGRepresentation(proImage.image,compressionNeeded);
}
```