# Upload image to server by compressing it

Tags: ios, image-compression

My file size is 15mb and I want to upload it to a server. I am using the following code and it is enabled for uploading. At the server side it is giving an error that the file is too large. It is working perfect for files up to 15mb in size.

```
-(UIImage *) resizeImage:(UIImage *)orginalImage resizeSize:(CGSize)size
{
    CGFloat actualHeight = orginalImage.size.height;
    CGFloat actualWidth = orginalImage.size.width;

    float oldRatio = actualWidth/actualHeight;
    float newRatio = size.width/size.height;
    if(oldRatio < newRatio)
    {
        oldRatio = size.height/actualHeight;
        actualWidth = oldRatio * actualWidth;
        actualHeight = size.height;
    }
    else
    {
        oldRatio = size.width/actualWidth;
        actualHeight = oldRatio * actualHeight;
        actualWidth = size.width;
    }

    CGRect rect = CGRectMake(0.0,0.0,actualWidth,actualHeight);
    UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(rect.size);
    [orginalImage drawInRect:rect];
    orginalImage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
    UIGraphicsEndImageContext();
    return orginalImage;

}
```

and 
where I want to compress I have written

```
proImage.image=[self resizeImage:proImage.image resizeSize:CGSizeMake(178,178)];
```

Comment: this code is resize the image but you have to compress with image uiimagepngrepresention..

Comment: but how to implement that dhaval....

Comment: if you want to resize your image then this code is perfect but if you want compress then you have to used this answer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20142358/compress-image-at-the-time-of-uploading

Comment: i have also used that code but...it is not working if imgage is too large...let say if image is 15 mb then loop goes continue and occupied memory was 1 gb ...and after sometime app got crashed

Comment: what you want exactly tell and write your whole code .... so get more idea?

Comment: i have used code that you have suggested to me...but i have one image of size 15mb and for that image this code is goes into loop....and after some time app. got crash...in memory management tools...I notice that when this loop is being execute 1 gb memory is occupied by app. and 100% CPU